# Performance of calls to table valued functions

Tags: performance, linq-to-sql

I have a table valued function foo(x). If I call this from SQL management studio, it runs in ~2 seconds, and returns ~20 rows. When I add it to a dbml, and from my code call `foo(x).toList()`, it takes about 5 times longer, ~10 seconds. What could cause the difference, and how can I mitigate the speed difference?

Comment: Have you tried profiling it? Something like Ants or dotTrace? Presumably your code has the overhead of opening and closing a connection for this?

Comment: I've used the Visual Studio profiler, but that doesn't help me much; the overhead is in that function, which I already knew. I'll take a look at what Ants or dotTrace can offer me.

Comment: try posting your linq query so others can see if there are any glaring issues.